# etags auto generation

Tags: emacs, elisp, etag

There were some people on stackoverflow having a problem like this but not exactly this and not exactly the solution I'm looking for. The problem is auto generating tag file by etags if the tag file didn't exist ( through emacs). I wanna log all the files and it is not limited to c or whatever and auto load it through emacs. I'm not interested in having any role in loading tag file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me I put the following line in my `makefile` file:

```
tags:
    find -type f -name "*.[ch]" -print0 | xargs -0 etags -o TAGS -a -l c
```

I refresh the tags with `M-!` compile, then `make tags`.

Emacs auto-detects that the TAGS file was refreshed, and asks you if you need to re-load it.

Otherwise, you can type `M-x` tags-reset-tags-table, and when you search something with `M-.`, Emacs auto-loads the new generated file.